# How Send a Dataset With 2 DataTable to Stimulsoft Report

Tags: c#, dataset, stimulsoft

I create a C# program and connected to stimulsoft for Make Reports.

I send a Dataset with 2 Datatable to my report with below code:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dtP.TableName = "dtP";
dtF.TableName = "dtF";
ds.Tables.Add(dtP);
ds.Tables.Add(dtF);
Report.RegData(ds);
Report.Show();
```

and "Report" is stireport object.

when my report page shown. my report is empty.

And when sent just 1 datatable as Dataset to my report that's work well.

---

**Solve:**

with add below code to my c# program can solve my problem:

```
objStiReport.Dictionary.Clear();
objStiReport.RegData(ds);
objStiReport.Dictionary.Synchronize();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had this problem. I tried many ways but no one solve the problem. I changed something in the dictionary in stimulsoft report designer.

1) choose the `Data from Dataset, DataTable` data adaptor type

2) Set a name for `Name In Source` property (for example `DS`)

3) Add some tables to `DS` and set the `Name In Source` of them to something like this `DS.Table1`. Note that it's important to set the `Name In Source` property of tables like this.

As I set the `Name In Source` property of tables like `DS.TableName`, the problem gone away for me.

Comment: Could you please describe more in detail how you did this part of your answer: 'Add some tables to DS'? I do not see any possibility how to add tables in designer? Thank you!

Comment: Excellent... my problem solved!!. I had such problem and it take  long time of me. your solution worked for me very well

Answer (score 2):

```
 1. Merge your 2 datables

dtP.Merge(dtF, false, MissingSchemaAction.Add);

 1. fill your report with datatable
Report.RegData(dtP);
```

another way (if datatable are not able to be merge ) is to create one datatable
with all column of each datatable

you can create a datarelation to establish a relationship 
between two datatables but can RegData method understand a relationship (datarelationp) ?

Comment: i can't. because dtp and dtf datatable has namesake columns. and i want create relationship between 2 datatables in stimulsoft.

Comment: when 2 datatables load in stimulsoft report, i create a relationship between 2 datatables and show in my report. but my problem is that i cant load 2 datatable in one report sametime.

Comment: I understand so you can make a single datatable from two datatables (create a new datatable that have column of each table) so you will provide only one datatable to your Report

Answer (score 0):

1. First open report with stimul report designer
2. In top of Dictionary tab, click on 'Action', and select 'Import XML Schema' and select your dataset file (with XSD extention) select 'Import XML Schema' and select your dataset file
3. For add other dataset repeat step 2 but select 'Merg XML Schema'
4. On your app code, use like this:

   ```
    StiReport report = new StiReport();
    report.Load(Server.MapPath(@"Report.mrt"));
    report.Compile();

    report.RegData(myDataSet1);
    report.RegData(myDataSet2);
    StiMobileViewer1.Report = report;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code:

```
            DataSet PrintData = GetDataFromDb();
            StiReport report = new();
            StiPdfExportSettings pdfSettings = new();
            string exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            string fileName = string.Concat(PrintFile, ".mrt");
            string printPath = Path.Combine(exePath, "Report", PrintDiscipline, fileName);
            ExportFile = string.Concat(ExportFile, "-", DateTime.Now.Year, "-", DateTime.Now.Month, "-", DateTime.Now.Day);
            for (int i = 0; i < PrintData.Tables.Count; i++)
            {
                report.RegData(PrintData.Tables[i].TableName, PrintData);
                report.Load(printPath);
                report.Render();
            }
            report.ExportDocument(StiExportFormat.Pdf, ExportFile + ".Pdf", pdfSettings);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Please add some more information about the code.