# Customiz (or Create) a table(StiTable) at runtime in C# (.NET4)

Tags: c#, methods, stimulsoft

I'm working on stimulsoft 2017.2.2 and C# (.NET4).
I have designed a report with footer and header , It is A4 and there is a table in it , based on stimulsofts method(DataGrid) to create a table at runtime I managed to change it to a report which accepts DataTable and everything works just fine on an empty project (.mrt file).
There is a table so i want to customize it there , Call it and customize it at runtime.

The problem is when I want to add this to my own file (.mrt) the table is empty , it only has 1 column and the rows are fine , the whole table is empty  but the design is visible.
So I will really appreciate If you could help me to sort this problem out.

My method looks like this :

```
private void PrintDataTable(string StiTableName, string DataSourceName, DataTable dataTable, StiReport report)
{

    DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);

    report.Compile();

    //script lang
    report.ScriptLanguage = StiReportLanguageType.CSharp;

    // Add data to datastore
    report.RegData(DataSourceName, dataView);

    // Fill dictionary
    report.Dictionary.Synchronize();

    //StiPage page = report.Pages.Items[0];

    // Create Table
    StiTable table = (StiTable)report[StiTableName];
    //StiTable table = (StiTable)report.GetComponentByName(StiTableName);
    table.DataSourceName = DataSourceName;
    table.AutoWidthType = StiTableAutoWidthType.LastColumns;
    table.ColumnCount = dataTable.Columns.Count;
    table.RowCount = 3;
    table.HeaderRowsCount = 1;
    table.FooterRowsCount = 1;
    //table.Width = page.Width;
    //table.Height = page.GridSize * 12;
    //table.DataSourceName = DataSourceName;
    table.CreateCell();
    table.TableStyleFX = new StiTable21StyleFX();
    table.TableStyle = Stimulsoft.Report.Components.Table.StiTableStyle.Style59;


    int indexHeaderCell = 0;
    int indexDataCell = dataTable.Columns.Count;
    //int indexDataCell = dataTable.Columns.Count;

    foreach (DataColumn column in dataView.Table.Columns)
    {
        // Set text on header
        StiTableCell headerCell = table.Components[indexHeaderCell] as StiTableCell;
        headerCell.Text.Value = column.Caption;
        headerCell.HorAlignment = StiTextHorAlignment.Center;
        headerCell.VertAlignment = StiVertAlignment.Center;


        StiTableCell dataCell = table.Components[indexDataCell] as StiTableCell;
        dataCell.HorAlignment = StiTextHorAlignment.Center;
        headerCell.VertAlignment = StiVertAlignment.Center;
        dataCell.Text.Value = "{" + DataSourceName + "." + Stimulsoft.Report.CodeDom.StiCodeDomSerializator.ReplaceSymbols(column.ColumnName) + "}";
        dataCell.Border = new StiBorder(StiBorderSides.All, Color.FromArgb(32, 178, 170), 1, StiPenStyle.Dash);
              
        indexHeaderCell++;
        indexDataCell++;
    }

    // Set text on footer
    StiTableCell footerCell = table.Components[table.Components.Count - 1] as StiTableCell;
    footerCell.Text.Value = "Count - {Count()}";
    footerCell.Font = new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Bold);
    footerCell.VertAlignment = StiVertAlignment.Center;
    footerCell.HorAlignment = StiTextHorAlignment.Center;

}
```

Thank you.

I'ts been 2 weeks and I even tried other ways like

```
report.GetComponentByName("Table1");
```

and still nothing ,
I really need this in short time ,
Will appreiciate your help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a HOTFIX:

```
private void PrintTableFine(StiReport report ,DataTable dataTable)
        {
            DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);

            report.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\A4 Portrait.mrt");

            report.ScriptLanguage = StiReportLanguageType.CSharp;

            // Add data to datastore
            report.RegData("view", dataView);

            // Fill dictionary
            report.Dictionary.Synchronize();

            StiPage page = report.Pages.Items[0];

            // Create Table
            StiTable table = new StiTable();
            table.Name = "Table1";
            table.AutoWidthType = StiTableAutoWidthType.LastColumns;
            table.ColumnCount = dataTable.Columns.Count;
            table.RowCount = 3;
            table.HeaderRowsCount = 1;
            table.FooterRowsCount = 1;
            table.Width = page.Width;
            table.Height = page.GridSize * 12;
            table.DataSourceName = "view" + dataView.Table.TableName;
            page.Components.Add(table);
            table.CreateCell();
            table.TableStyleFX = new StiTable21StyleFX();
            table.TableStyle = Stimulsoft.Report.Components.Table.StiTableStyle.Style31;

            int indexHeaderCell = 0;
            int indexDataCell = dataTable.Columns.Count;

            foreach (DataColumn column in dataView.Table.Columns)
            {
                // Set text on header
                StiTableCell headerCell = table.Components[indexHeaderCell] as StiTableCell;
                headerCell.Text.Value = column.Caption;
                headerCell.Font = new Font("IRANSans(FaNum)", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
                headerCell.HorAlignment = StiTextHorAlignment.Center;
                headerCell.VertAlignment = StiVertAlignment.Center;
                headerCell.Border = new StiBorder(StiBorderSides.All, Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0), 1, StiPenStyle.Dash);

                StiTableCell dataCell = table.Components[indexDataCell] as StiTableCell;
                dataCell.Text.Value = "{view" + dataView.Table.TableName + "." +
                    Stimulsoft.Report.CodeDom.StiCodeDomSerializator.ReplaceSymbols(column.ColumnName) + "}";
                dataCell.Font = new Font("IRANSans(FaNum)", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
                dataCell.HorAlignment = StiTextHorAlignment.Center;
                dataCell.VertAlignment = StiVertAlignment.Center;
                dataCell.Border = new StiBorder(StiBorderSides.All, Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0), 1, StiPenStyle.Dash);

                indexHeaderCell++;
                indexDataCell++;
            }

            // Set text on footer
            StiTableCell footerCell = table.Components[table.Components.Count - 1] as StiTableCell;
            //footerCell.Text.Value = "Count - {Count()}";
            footerCell.Font = new Font("IRANSans(FaNum)", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
            footerCell.VertAlignment = StiVertAlignment.Center;
            footerCell.HorAlignment = StiTextHorAlignment.Center;
        }
```

Actually it creates a table.
Please remember , to use it like this :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 

            StiReport report = new StiReport();

            //Reminder: compiling is after the table 

            //table: 
            PrintTableFine(report,dt);

            report.Compile();

            //adding a variable:
            report["Variable"] = "var1ا";
           
            report.Render(false);
            report.Show();
```

Just give it a DataTable and it will create a table with header and footer.
Reminder: the report which your adding this table to SHOULD NOT HAVE A (Sti)TABLE IN IT(in the design).